# Appium : When I copy past the code generated by Appium in eclipse And try to run it - Nothing happens

Tags: appium

Appium : When I copy past the code generated by Appium in eclipse And try to run it - Nothing happens

Hi All,

I am new to Appium and trying it out.I have got it setup and every thing is fine.When i record a code in generated.
So, what i did i copy past that code in eclipse and then try to run as testng.But nothing happens

What should I run it as (testng/junit or what)
I have just pasted the code so No testng in picture.I read some where to run it as testng so i did 
My problem is that I want to launch the emulator and run my recorded script on it.

Please help me I have a demo for appium after 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code here.

Also , you can check my post on iOS Appium [here](http://smritituteja.in/?p=111) on my site.

If you are not using testng -> just run it as normal Java Application.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps. it worked for. From your question, I see you are using Java webdriver.

1. Make sure "Pre Launch" is not selected in your appium settings. Provider the .ipa/.app file. And Launch Appium. Make sure it starts without error.
2. Open your code using eclipse and run, it should launch the simulator (you can specify the device and simulator type in your code).

If code is not compiling, provide required libraries i.e. selenium-server (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/). It will work for sure.

-Vinay